# Ionic3 Algolia Firestore Search - Importing Issue

Tags: typescript, firebase, ionic3, google-cloud-firestore, algolia

I am trying to fetch some product list from algolia backend. 
I tried to add algolia to the ionic3 app using the following command

```
npm install instantsearch.js --save
```

but in importing the instantsearch in the page throws the following error

***Could not find a declaration file for module 'instantsearch.js/es/widgets'. '../algoliaIntegration/node_modules/instantsearch.js/es/widgets/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm install @types/instantsearch.js` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'instantsearch.js';`***

i tried to import using both the below methods

1-

```
import instantsearch from 'instantsearch.js/es';

import { searchBox } from 'instantsearch.js/es/widgets';
```

2-

```
import * as instantsearch from 'instantsearch.js'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a file with an fitting (or empty) definition in your project root. You can call it `instantsearch.d.ts`

```
declare module 'instantsearch.js/es' {
}

declare module 'instantsearch.js/es/widgets' {
}
```

Then you could also add a more complete definition file later (something we plan to do in the future from Algolia's side, but not yet right now

Comment: I added an empty file named "instantsearch.d.ts" with values
    "declare module 'instantsearch.js/es' {
    }

   declare module 'instantsearch.js/es/widgets' {
    }"
 and copied in the project root of the ionic where www and src are located but still the error persists

Comment: Can you make a project I can clone?

Comment: please use this repo "https://github.com/geass619/algoliaIntegrationIonic.git" i have added a sample project in ionic3 and tried to import in home page, causes error

Comment: where you able to do a build using the repo,if not will help you

Comment: Public holiday today, will look tomorrow

Comment: Hey @vv619, just took a look, but seems like you're using Angular 2. In that case you can use Angular InstantSearch which is already optimised for TypeScript and Angular: https://community.algolia.com/angular-instantsearch/getting-started.html

Comment: its for ionic3 application but let me check whether that will work, thanks

Comment: Send an email to support@algolia.com if you have other issues setting it up